# Showing existence and uniqueness of a number with the following property

Tags: complex-analysis

In the following let $z,w\in \mathbb C$ and $\langle z,w\rangle := \mathrm{Re}(z \overline{w})$. I would like to prove that for $z,w$ nonzero there exist a unique real number $\omega \in (-\pi,\pi]$ such that

$$ \cos \omega = {\langle z,w \rangle \over |z| |w|}$$

and

$$ \sin \omega = {\langle iz,w \rangle \over |z| |w|}$$

but I can't prove it. My idea was to use that

$$ ({\langle z,w \rangle \over |z| |w|})^2 + ({\langle iz,w \rangle \over |z| |w|})^2 =1$$

for all $z,w$ but it doesn't help. My other idea was to draw the picture of the unit circle and look at the angle between $z$ and $w$ but then there is no right triangle which I would need for the sine and cosine.

> How to prove existence and uniqueness of $\omega$?

Comment: See [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: @Anna: did you find what you were looking for?

Comment: @AlexH. Yes, thank you, your answer has been very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One basic way: first notice that you can assume $z$ and $w$ are of norm $1$ (since $z = |z|z'$ and $w=|w|w'$ imply $(z,w)=|z||w|(z',w')$.

So they're both on the unitary circle and you can write $z=e^{ia}$ and $w=e^{ib}$.

Then $(z,w)=\cos a \cos b + \sin a \sin b = \cos (a-b)$ and $(iz,w)=\cos a \sin b - \sin a \cos b = \sin (a-b)$.

So your angle is $\omega = a-b$.

NB: your approach is good too. If you have already shown that $(z,w)^2+(iz,w)^2=|zw|^2$ (good fun), you can use the following fact: if $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x,y>0$ (to simplify), there exists a unique $\theta \in (0,\pi/2)$ s.t. $x=\cos \theta$ and $y=\sin \theta$.

To see it, notice that $x$ has to be $>0$ and $<1$. Since $\cos$ is bijective from $(0,\pi/2)$ to $(0,1)$, there is a unique $\theta$ st $x=\cos \theta$. But then $y^2 = 1-x^2 = 1-\cos^2 \theta=\sin^2 \theta$. Since we assumed $y>0$ and $\theta \in (0,\pi/2)$, this implies $y=\sin \theta$.

You get the other cases ($x<0$ or $y<0$) by replacing $x$ by $-x$ and using trigonometric translations.